# Highlight menu style changes elements on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a one page website made up of 5 different sections with a fixed nav at the top. In this nav I have 5 links that link to the corresponsing section of the page. When clicked, it smoothly scrolls down to that section. The problem I'm having is with the active class. At the top of the page, the "about" link has an active class which adds a thick border to the bottom of the link. But when I scroll down to the next section "riding areas", I want the active class to remove itself from "about" and add itself to "riding areas".

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="desktop-navbar">
    <img class="logo-desktop" src="img/logo-desktop.png">
    <div id="desktop-nav">
        <a href="#5">CONTACT</a>            
        <a href="#4">PRICING AND SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#3">FACILITY</a>
        <a href="#2">RIDING AREAS</a>
        <a href="#1" class="active">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.desktop-navbar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: fixed;
}
#desktop-nav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Chau Philomene One', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 43px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
a.active {
    border-bottom: thick solid #F15B29;
}
```

I know this can be accomplished using jQuery, but I haven't been able to find a way that works for me, and I'm not very fluent in JS so I'm uncertain as to how to go about this.

Comment: [Bootstrap Scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/scrollspy) is easy to set up and use.

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone Would you happen to know how I can use ScrollSpy without adding Bootstrap css to my website? When I add the Bootstrap links to my site, nearly all of my styles change to Bootstrap styles..

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS you may add `id` attribute to each `<a>` tag and then use `let elem = document.getElementById('your id')` to find the certain link. And then add or remove necessary class by `elem.classList.add/remove("class")`. Or use `elem.classList.toggle("class")` for toggle class.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested, using a plugin like [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/scrollspy) would be easier and gives better accuracy in responsive views taking care of different viewports. But this is how we can do it using jQuery :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var links=$('#desktop-nav a');
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    //Change Class when we load the pageUrl with an anchor hash ex : page.html#1
    var hash = window.location.hash;
        if(hash) {
        links.removeClass('active');
        $('#desktop-nav a[href="' + hash +'"]').addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top + 'px'
        }, 1000, 'swing');
    }
    //Change The class OnClick
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        links.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing');
    });
});
//Handle scrolling event
function onScroll(event){
var margin=75; //close to the sticky menu height here
var links=$('#desktop-nav a');
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    links.each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var elm = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        //check if scrolling position is matching the active anchor id
        if ((elm.position().top)+margin <= scrollPos && elm.position().top + elm.height() > (scrollPos+margin)) {
            links.removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.desktop-navbar {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: fixed;
}
#desktop-nav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Chau Philomene One', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 43px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
a.active {
    border-bottom: thick solid #F15B29;
}
section{padding-top:75px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop-navbar">
    <img class="logo-desktop" src="img/logo-desktop.png">
    <div id="desktop-nav">
        <a href="#5">CONTACT</a>            
        <a href="#4">PRICING AND SERVICES</a>
        <a href="#3">FACILITY</a>
        <a href="#2">RIDING AREAS</a>
        <a href="#1" class="active">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
</div>
<section id="1">
<h2>ABOUT US</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
<section id="2">
<h2>Riding spots</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
<section id="3">
<h2>Facility</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
<section id="4">
<h2>Pricing and services</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
<section id="5">
<h2>Contact Us</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
<section id="footer">
<h2>Footer Links/widgets...</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
</section>
```